# Unable to get wsdl from service with multiple bindings hosted in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, wsdl

I have a WCF 4.5 Service hosted in IIS7.5.
The service is using netTcpBinding for Net 3.5+ clients and basicHttpBinding for Silverlight 5 clients. The address on this binding is specific (**address="SL"**).
ServiceMetadata "httpGetEnabled" is set to true.
Now I would like to consume this service from BIRT, so I'm trying to get a wsdl file.
I can't figure out what URL is to be used because IIS is rejecting the request.

Following are the interresting part of the configuration file :

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
    <add factory="My.CustomServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="~/My.AdminService.svc" service="My.AdminService" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<services>
  <service name="My.AdminService">
    <endpoint address="SL" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_SL"
     name="BasicHttpBinding_IAcadmin" contract="My.AdminService.IAcadmin" />
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
     contract="My.AdminService.IAcadmin">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
     contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The service is published at the following URL :

```
http://localhost/My.AdminService
```

Now, if I'm understanding things correctly, the WSDL address would be :

```
http://localhost/My.AdminService/My.AdminService.svc/SL/?wsdl
```

This URL is rejected by IIS with a 404 error.

This seems to be a IIS problem not a WCF one. Anyway, am I using the right URL ?

Any Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `http://localhost/My.AdminService/SL` ? Does this folder ecists? If you put there plain html - can you open it in browser?

Comment: Yes I tried it, and error 404.0 is returned. The folder does not exist. If I create it and put a file in it, I can open it in a browser. Notice that a WCF call to http://localhost/My.AdminService/My.AdminService.svc will succeed.

Comment: @omatrot: Did you ever find out what was the problem? I having the same issue

Comment: @David: unfortunately, no.